# Google Yolo Custom Styles / CSP Support

Tags: google-api, google-identity, google-smartlockpasswords

`googleyolo` injects `<style>` into the html document. This violates my CSP policy which restricts inline styles. Would it be possible to either disable `<style>` injecting or support injecting with a `nonce` attribute like `<style nonce="randomBase64StringFromServer">` If style injection is disabled, it would be nice to be able to export the styles so I can inject them myself instead of hardcoding the css.

Comment: We're working on a fix.

Comment: Hi Connor, we deployed a fix to the CSP violation. Please let me know if that works for you!